# how to launch a customized exe file as administartor at the end of the Wix installation

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

All

I create a wix installer to do following task:

at the end of the installation (before clicking Finish), launch the customized "Run.exe" to install "VS Redistributable" and launch the main application "Converter".

My code cannot launch the "Converter" and get the error message "Failed to launch Converter for Windows." from "Converter".

But the "Converter" can be launched when I run the installer using following command in a Command line prompt opened as administrator.

```
msiexec.exe /i C:\ConverterWixSetup64.msi /L*vx c:\Log.txt
```

Any code change to be made to launch "Run.exe" as administrator so it can launch the "Converter" without running as administrator in command prompt?

Wix code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <?include "..\include\Variables.wxi" ?>
    <Fragment>
      <CustomAction Id='LaunchApplication' Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand='cmd.exe /c Run.exe' Execute='deferred' Impersonate='no' Return='asyncNoWait' />
    </Fragment>
</Wix>


<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="LaunchApplication" Before="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Run.exe code to launch "Converter":

```
//_tprintf(_T("\nLaunching %s..."), appDisplayName);
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
//start Converter application
if (!CreateProcess(appName, NULL, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    //if failed to open, give user feed back
    /*_tprintf(_T("\n>  %s failed to launch."), appDisplayName);
    _tprintf(_T("\n%s"), closingApp);*/
    MessageBox(NULL, appFailedString.c_str(), failedToOpenConverterForWindows, MB_OK);
    return 3;
}
HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
//WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion.

Try to download and install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package. Then, check your Windows updates and complete any updates specifically for the above product.

I hope this could help your problem.